# using xpath get the correct value in selectName

Tags: xpath

Below I have written the  code. I need help to get the right value in  **selectName.** I am new to XPath.  Basically with this code I am trying to achieve if employeeName = Chris I need to return 23549 to the calling function. Please help.

**Part of the code:**

```
public static string getEmployeeeID(string employeeName)
{

    Cache cache = HttpContext.Current.Cache;
    string cacheNameEmployee = employeeName + "Tech";

if (cache[cacheNameEpm] == null)
        {
            XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("inc/xml/" + SiteManager.Site.ToString() + "TechToolTip.xml"));
            XPathNavigator navigator = doc.CreateNavigator();
            string selectName = "/Technologies/Technology[FieldName='" + fieldName + "']/EpmId";
            XPathNodeIterator nodes = navigator.Select(selectName);

            if (nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                if (nodes.Current.Name.Equals("FieldName"))
                //nodes.Current.MoveToParent();
                //nodes.Current.MoveToParent();
                //nodes.Current.MoveToChild("//EpmId");

                cache.Add(cacheNameEpm, nodes.Current.Value, null, DateTime.Now + new TimeSpan(4, 0, 0), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Default, null);
            }
        }
        return  cache[cacheNameEpm] as string;
    }
```

**XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <EName>Chris</EName>
    <ID>23556</ID>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <EName>CBailey</EName>
    <ID>22222</ID>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <EName>Meghan</EName>
    <ID>12345</ID>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

**PLEASE NOTE:This XML file has 100  nodes. I just put 1 to indicate the structure.**

Comment: What's not working in your code?  What have you done to try and figure out what's wrong?

Comment: You are selecting /Employee/EName, but the full path of the EName node is /Employees/Employee/EName ... ?

Comment: Fixed the selectName. Also, the if statement is incorrect!!

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

- the slash characters do not need to be doubled ex "/Employee/EName"
  (unless there may be additional nodes between the nodes listed)
- the first path should be: "/Employees/Employee[EName='" + employeeName + "']";
- the second path should be "ID"  (case sensitive, for sure)
- the current locig seems to have one too many GotoParent

  regarding the statement of not using  //,  I'm not sure, it depends on the XML schema.  I don't understand why moving back to parents etc.. maybe if you elaborate on this, we can make sense of it.....

Some of my confusion is with trying to reuse the current logic.  In truth you would only need one XPATH navigation to get you what you need:

```
"/Employees/Employee[EName="' + employeeName + "']/ID"
```

The above means: from the root (single starting slash), find child element , then it child  which has a child named EName *with a value of employeeName*. Then get the ID "sibling" of this EName node.

Some of my hesitation however is with the double slashes, which in XPATH mean any node done the path not necessary the next one.  If all the Employee records are not going to be like the one shown in the sample, you may need it, and maybe complicate the XPATH part that get the ID, acordingly.

**EDIT:**  one last thing...  (explaining why you are getting *all* the values in the file rather than just the ID for the selected employee name)

You need to call **nodes.MoveNext()**,  prior to using the XPathNodeIterator Current property.
In short the section following the navigator.Select() call could be like:

```
if (nodes.Count == 0)
{
    return ""; // not found !
}
else
{
    nodes.MoveNext();    // <<< That was the missing culprit...
    retVal = nodes.Current.Value;
}
```

Comment: Okay. Can you elaborate on the "second path should be ID" please? I will make al lthe changes you recommended. Thanks!!

Comment: Note: any paths starting with "/" are absolute paths, from the root (just before the first node). Any paths not starting with "/" are relative paths, which are searched from the current position.

Comment: Oh! So the if statement is incorrect. What I need is the value of fieldName - which is the parameter passed to the function? and 
also contains the same value in FieldName which is part of the XML tag too.

Comment: @Joren, yes, with multiple nodes the slash is needed and indicative of a relative path),  but in the case of ID,  one would either need "//ID" (to get any ID down the line) or "ID" (to get the direct child/children named ID),  as /ID would find nothing since the root is <Employees>

Comment: XPath expression should be what he needs, but one minor nit - if `employeeName` is a string literal, it has to be quoted as well (presumably by single quotes), and it might be a good idea to account for having a single quote in the name as well. Since XPath 1.0 doesn't have escape sequences in string literals, this would require a `concat`-translation.

Comment: This XML file has 100  nodes. I just put 1 to indicate the structure. I still have to read all the comments/suggestions.

Comment: @Pavel Thank you! somehow I had deleted them.   (I just added edited these quotes back in)

Comment: @Sangeeta  If all 100 nodes have the same structure than the <employee> node shown for "Chris", and if they are all siblings of Chris,  then you do not need to double the slashes for sure.

Comment: MJV, I am confused now. Let me make edits to my original xml File above and then let me know what I need to do. Thanks fro all the wonderful suggestions!!

Comment: okay I got it. But what should I do in the if (nodes.Count > 0) statement. Please advice!1

Comment: I just need the id. Do i even need the  if (nodes.Count > 0) statement.

Comment: @Sangeeta  looking better.  attention  1) the name of the element nodes are wrong (i.e. differ from the sample file)   2) in the test following the nodes.counts > 0,  you should test for Current.Name to be "ID"  (or "empId" per the alternate set of names),  for that is where XPATH took you.

Comment: @Sangeeta:  I would use the naviagor.SelectSingleNode() instead, and test for its return value to not be null (It would mean "not found"), rather than dealing with the nodes (XPathNodeIterator) object

Comment: sorry about point (1) I will fix it and then you take a look to see if it looks ok now. I am concerned about the if statement. Give me a second!!

Comment: string selectName = "/Employees/Employee[EName='" + employeeName + "']/ID";
XPathNodeIterator nodes = navigator.SelectSingleNode(selectName);

Is that what you were implying

Comment: @Sangeta: yes, for the path.  But, you can't use nodes with SelectSingleNode (different return type),   so why don't you stick with Select() and then use nodes.Current.Value to the employee ID value...

Comment: okay. I will test it out. I am close. Thank you for the wonderful help in this forum!!

Comment: @mjv Please help!! I hve all the syntax fixed at this point. Now I need to extract and return the value for ID. THis is my last working statement:  XPathNodeIterator nodes = navigator.Select(selectName); Do I use if or switch. There is 1 matching node found at this point!!

Comment: what's the value of nodes.Current.Value ?  is it what we expect, i.e. just the Employee ID ?

Comment: @mjv Thanks for responding - Well I assigned string t = nodes.Current.value; and it got a long string of all NameId from the xml file.

Comment: @Sangeeta.  See my response.  Issue is with missing MoveNext() on the iterator !    You should be _all set_ !!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the "ID" value for the employee called "Chris", you should be able to do this:

```
string selectName = "/Employees/Employee[EName='" + employeeName + "']/ID";
XPathNodeIterator idNode = navigator.Select(selectName);
```

This should give you the XPath:

```
/Employees/Employee[EName='Chris']/ID
```

and that should select that particular node right away. It gives you the `ID` element of the `Employee` with the `EName=Chris` inside the `Employees` collection; that's what you're looking for, right?

If you want to select just single node and inspect its values, use this snippet of code:

```
XPathNavigator empNode = navigator.SelectSingleNode(selectName);

if(empNode != null)
{
   string id = empNode.Value;
}
```

If you want only a single node - why do you use the `Select` method which returns an iterator over a whole list of nodes anyway?

Or if you want to stick to your original approach for some reason, you need to do a `.MoveNext()` first before reading the value:

```
XPathNodeIterator nodes = navigator.Select(selectName);

if (nodes.Count > 0)
{
   if (nodes.MoveNext())
   {
       string IDvalue = nodes.Current.Value;
   }
}
```

Now, in this case, you have just Chris' ID's value in your string.

Marc

Comment: Here's the code:  string selectName = "/Employees/Employee[EName='" + employeeName + "']/ID";  XPathNodeIterator idNode = navigator.Select(selectName);    string tr = nodes.Current.Value; Now if I do as you said tr contains all names and id as 1 string. Not the id associated with Chris. Please help!!

Comment: @Sangeeta: to select a single node and inspect it, use `SelectSingleNode` instead of just Select which returns an iterator over a list of nodes!